# Unable to load config file in Java in Heroku

Tags: java, heroku

I'm developing a REST (Jersey) service in Java and I use Hibernate to connect to a MySQL database. The problem is I'm able to run the program perfectly fine when I run it locally but it fails to load the hibernate.cfg.xml if I deploy it and run from Heroku.

This is the error I get:

```
org.hibernate.HibernateException: hibernate.cfg.xml not found
    at org.hibernate.internal.util.ConfigHelper.getResourceAsStream(ConfigHelper.java:173)
    at org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration.getConfigurationInputStream(Configuration.java:2093)
    at org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration.configure(Configuration.java:2074)
    at com.example.services.HibernateUtilities.buildSessionFactory(HibernateUtilities.java:17)
    at com.example.services.HibernateUtilities.<init>(HibernateUtilities.java:10)
    at com.example.services.TimeService.get(TimeService.java:22)
    at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor9.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:616)
```

My project setup:

[image]

HibernateUtilities.java

[image]

Once again, this exact program runs perfectly file when I run it locally using:

```
foreman start web
```

Thanks!

Comment: Can you solved this problem? I have the same issue in my app :/, Thanks!

Comment: Create a source folder and copy your hibernate config file to it. Double check that the file is in build path. If this still doesnt work, add this source folder to your pom.xml (assuming you are using maven) as dependency. That worked for me!